# Create office 365 user with PHP API

Tags: php, api, graph, office365, crud

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/graph/tutorials/php) tutorial to set up a laravel enviroment to work with the Microsoft Graph API. I want to do CRUD operations on Office 365 users, but in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body), there is no PHP sample code provided.

This is what the request body should look like:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
 Content-type: application/json

 {
   "accountEnabled": true,
   "displayName": "displayName-value",
   "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
   "userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com",
   "passwordProfile" : {
   "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
   "password": "password-value"
  }
 }
```

However, How do I translate that to a PHP call?

Comment: Did you tried `curl` ?

Comment: No, can you provide some more info?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code

Comment: @AdamWhateverson i have set up the oAuth and everything already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post that as a PHP Curl request.
Here is the basic idea to get you started.

```
$jsonStr = json_encode(Array(
    "param1"=>"val1",
    "param2"=>"val2",
    "param3"=>Array(
                "param1"=>"val1",
                "param2"=>"val2"
    )
));
$headers = Array("Content-Type: application/json","Content-Length:".strlen($jsonStr));

$ch = curl_init("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonStr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks, how should I do it with that nested object 'passwordProfile'?

Comment: The PHP function json_encode can encode nested arrays, I have update the example to show nested

Comment: thanks for the update. i know this is a bit out of scope, but where in the laravel framework do I put this post request to actually be executed? I am a total Angular user and new to Php so please bear with me :)

Comment: I don't use Laravel sorry. For me it looks completely foreign and if you have already managed to get access tokens you should have a good idea roughly on what to do next.  In all honesty, I would go to a Laravel forum and ask that question as it is very specific to them. This might help? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests

Comment: Hi @Adam Whateverson,  sorry to bother you again but how do I implement the auth token into the $headers variable, so I can create users to my Office365 tenant application?

Comment: It's a big question to ask but here's my process for my project.

1). Request an Authorisation Code from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize and pass it the client_id, response_type=code and response_uri

2) Once I have that code,I exchange it for an access token by sending it to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token and using grant_type "authorization_code".

3). With my access token I can make graph requests as long as the access token is included in a header via Authorization: Bearer [access_token]

That's the basic flow.